# Error extracting Ruby on fresh Debian install

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've just provisioned 2 new Debian servers, and it looks like RVM cannot extract Ruby. What extraction dependency am I missing?

Console Output:
There has been an error while trying to extract the source. Halting the installation.

Screenshot: http://d.pr/i/JO2Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log explicitly says "please read ...extract.log". My bet is you had insufficient space on your storage device, but you should definitely inspect that log file.